# Flutter Google Map Crash on all screen

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

** Flutter version **
Flutter 3.0.1
Dart 2.17.1
DevTools 2.12.2

** Packages Used **
google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.6
geolocator: ^8.2.1
geocoding: ^2.0.4

** Added Permission manifest file **

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
  android:value="Google Map Key" />

<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<uses-library
  android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
  android:required="false" />
```

** Added in gradle properties file **

android.enableDexingArtifactTransform=false

** Code **

```
    GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: plex,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
      ),
```

** Issue **

D/MapsInitializer(5575): preferredRenderer: null

D/zzca (5575): preferredRenderer: null

I/zzca (5575): Making Creator dynamically

Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:203115000

Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 203115000

V/DynamiteModule(5575): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils

I/Google Maps Android API(5575): Google Play services client version: 12451000

I/Google Maps Android API(5575): Google Play services package version: 221514037

W/MobStoreFlagStore( 5575): at agw.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221514081@22.15.14(150400-0):3)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5577): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

E/AndroidRuntime( 5577): at java.nio.ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.put(ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5577): at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.n.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221514081@22.15.14 (150400-0):2)

Comment: Did you actually add your API key?

Comment: Yeah... But no Idea regarding this error

Comment: Did U get any solution? I am running into this problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: still no solution !! but what i did was - just waited till GoogleMap is loaded first and then added marker and polyline, instead of animateCamera(), used moveCamera() with zoom 18, By doing this Google Map was not crushing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps will fix the problem (update to new renderer in kotlin project):

1. Add this line to your app's build.gradle:

   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
2. Import these lines to MainActivity.kt:

   ```
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.Renderer
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapsSdkInitializedCallback
   ```
3. Add `MapsInitializer.initialize(applicationContext, Renderer.LATEST, this)` in your MainActivity onCreate method.

Implement OnMapsSdkInitializedCallback interface for verify the new renderer.
example (MainActivity.kt):

```
package com.example.application

import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.view.FlutterMain
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.Renderer
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapsSdkInitializedCallback


class MainActivity: FlutterActivity(), OnMapsSdkInitializedCallback{
    override 
    fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MapsInitializer.initialize(applicationContext, Renderer.LATEST, this)
    }

    override fun onMapsSdkInitialized(renderer: MapsInitializer.Renderer) {
      when (renderer) {
        Renderer.LATEST -> Log.d("NewRendererLog", "The latest version of the renderer is used.")
        Renderer.LEGACY -> Log.d("NewRendererLog","The legacy version of the renderer is used.")
      }
    }
}
```

4. Run & Check the logs, you should see these lines:

D/MapsInitializer: loadedRenderer: LATEST
D/NewRendererLog: The latest version of the renderer is used.

source
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105965#issuecomment-1224473127

Comment: how about on IOS bro?

Answer (score 1):

The wifi of the emulator was turned off and when I turned it on the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue, but when i add this code

```
if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    AndroidGoogleMapsFlutter.useAndroidViewSurface = true;
  }
```

my map run. you can add in void main.

Comment: Yeah.. i have added.. But still getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the google map package:

```
google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.6
```

change the package like below :

```
google_maps_flutter:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/lukaskurz/plugins
      path: packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter
      ref: main
```

And the application is working fine without any crash